# AWS CLI search resource by tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am trying to use AWS CLI to search for resources by tags.

I prepare this `tag.json` file:

> {
>       "TagFilters": [                 {
>                       "Value": "postgres-dev",
>                       "Key": "Name"
>                   }
>               ]
>    }

and use this command:

> aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters --cli-input-json file://tag.json

However, instead of returning only the databases which have this tag, it returns every resource in my AWS account (EC2, ELB, etc.)

Can anyone show me where did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you try it in plain text syntax in place of JSON?

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters "Key=Name,Values=postgres-dev"
```

For multiple filters (with AND):

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources \
  --tag-filters "Key=Name,Values=postgres-dev" "Key=Test,Values=second"
```

Also, I think should be "Values", not "Value".

Let me know ;)

Update with JSON syntax:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --cli-input-json file://tag.json
```

JSON body:

```
{ "TagFilters": [ { "Key": "Name", "Values": [ "postgres-dev" ] } ] }
```

Comment: I tried with plain text syntax. It worked like a charm. But I prefer having a JSON file, so I can template it, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you try this command with this JSON body?

aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --cli-input-json file://tag.json

Comment: {
    "TagFilters": [
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Values": [
                "postgres-dev"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Hey man, it works! What did I do wrong? I only see you Values to become a list, isn't it? Please put your comment into your answer, I will mark it as Accepted :D

Comment: Answer updated, I think you were missing the --cli-input-json parameter ;)

Comment: no, from my post above, you can see that I have it. I will test again :)

Comment: Ok it works, then I don't know why it didn't :( Anw, thanks so much for your time :)