# Get ARNs of all resources in Cloudformation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

What is the easiest way to get the ARN of each resource created by Cloudformation?

I'm trying to find an easy way to do this, so that I can collect this information and send it to an external monitoring/topology tool, to use to build relationships between components.

As far as I can see there's no simple way to get the ARNs of each resource in Cloudformation.

I figured that:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name <stack-name-here>
```

might work, but I don't get the ARN from this.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `describe-stack-resources` (or [`list-stack-resource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stack-resources.html)) were to return ARN values, you could have been able to extract certain fields of the result through [`--query` flag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html). However, the CLI commands for listing AWS resources in a stack do not provide ARNs. Even the output fields `LogicalResourceId`, `PhysicalResourceId` and `ResourceType` apparently cannot be used for a second query to get the ARNs separately.

You may make use of [`get-resources`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html) command of `resourcegroupstaggingapi` which [returns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html#output) a list of tags and resource ARNs. If you are **tagging** all of your resources with, for example, a stack name; you should be able to call it like:

```sh
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters "Key=stackName,Values=myStackName"
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594359/aws-cli-search-resource-by-tags) for further discussion and visit this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_GetResources.html#API_GetResources_Examples) in docs of how its output looks like.

Comment: Aha nice, that could work in at least some scenarions, typically we apply a "Stack" tag, so that might work - I'll give it a go, thanks for the great answer! Shame that you can't get the ARN directly from the cloudformation response though.

I was going to go down the route of converting the PhysicalResourceId and Type to the ARN, but it's too messy for all the different resources.